# Robotium - installing the target app as part of the build

Tags: android, maven, emulation, robotium, instrumentation

I'm trying to run a Robotium testing suite on a demo application, but the android maven plugin fails at mvn install after pushing the test application to the device, because it can't find the target app.

The error is

```
Test run failed to complete: Unable to find instrumentation target package: com.example.app
```

And indeed, the demo application is not pushed on the emulator as part of the build. If I push it manually, then the testing suite runs succesfully.

The parent pom.xml contains both modules (the demo app and the test app which has a dependency on the demo app), and the mvn package builds them both successfully, but it only pushes the test app to the emulator.

Any idea what I need to change to push the demo app to the emulator before the test app?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue on my project by adding the following depedencies in de test module:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>appartifact</artifactId>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>appartifact</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>apk</type>
    </dependency>
```